# Devise routes for API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, devise

How can I understand the following error message (when testing) and why when making a post request to my registrations controller create action, I am using `/lnf.json`?

In my routes I have the following constraints and path setup

```
constraints(subdomain: 'api') do
  devise_for :users, path: 'lnf', controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
end
```

And my Registrations Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def create
   super
  end

end
```

If I make a post request via curl to `http://api.local.dev:3000/lnf.json` I get the response I require.

When I want to test this using Rspec I have a simple test setup

```
post :create, format: :json, :user => {user params here}
```

But I get an error when running the test

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
Could not find devise mapping for path "/lnf.json?
```

### Edit

Output of Rake routes as requested

```
 new_user_session GET    /lnf/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
        user_session POST   /lnf/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
destroy_user_session DELETE /lnf/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
       user_password POST   /lnf/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
   new_user_password GET    /lnf/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
  edit_user_password GET    /lnf/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit {:subdomain=>"api"}
                     PATCH  /lnf/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
                     PUT    /lnf/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
   user_confirmation POST   /lnf/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
 new_user_confirmation GET    /lnf/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

registrations controller

```
 cancel_user_registration GET    /lnf/cancel(.:format)           registrations#cancel {:subdomain=>"api"}
   user_registration POST   /lnf(.:format)                  registrations#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
  new_user_registration GET    /lnf/sign_up(.:format)          registrations#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
 edit_user_registration GET    /lnf/edit(.:format)             registrations#edit {:subdomain=>"api"}
                     PATCH  /lnf(.:format)                  registrations#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
                     PUT    /lnf(.:format)                  registrations#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
                     DELETE /lnf(.:format)                  registrations#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
                 lnf POST   /lnf(.:format)                  registrations#create {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>"json"}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like devise_for routes part need tune a little bit (or add special route for your case with lnf aka "post '/lnf', to: 'registrations#create', defaults: {format: 'json'}"). 
could you please put output of 'rake routes | grep devise' command here?

Comment: Thanks, i have updated with the route for registrations#create, do you want all the routes ?

Comment: with this special route how would i override the route provided by my current setup ?

Comment: could you, please show me output of 
`rake routes | grep devise`

Comment: did you try use :subdomain=>"api"  in test params?
post :create,  subdomain: "api", format: :json, :user => {user params here}

I think that you can get some ideas from this discussion https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/789

Comment: yes I have tried that, `subdomain: :api` and `subdomain: 'api'`

Comment: What routes for registrations controller?
`rake routes | grep registration`

Comment: try put registrations controller in devise namespace